# Should BackgroundTask registration names be unique across apps?

Tags: windows-8

When registering a `BackgroundTask` using `BackgroundTaskBuilder`, the `Name` property can be set to identify the task. The sample application shows this property being used to subsequently locate the task when it's already registered.

Should this name be unique across multiple applications; can other applications detect my application's background tasks if they look for the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not something to worry about. App-specific information like this is isolated between apps. There won't be name conflicts, nor will other apps be able to access anything in yours. The same principle applies to APIs like the credential locker, app data, secondary tiles, and so forth.